# Load local XML file - Chrome 14

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I've been trying to get Chrome to load and transform local files. I can attach a style sheet to XML files and that works fine (once the --allow-file-access-from-files switch is added to the command line). However, when trying to load files using xmlHTTPRequest pretty much exactly as in the question [Loading local XML file in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578979/loading-local-xml-file-in-chrome) (see below), it fails on the line `xmlHttp.send(null)`.

Does anyone know why or can offer assistance?

Here's the code from that question:

```
function readxml()
{
    xmlHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
}
```

The version of Chrome there was 12, I'm using 14 but I wouldn't have thought that would make a difference.

#### Edit

Ghosty's answer got me one more step, it got *send* to work. Now the *xmlHttp.responseXML* object is null. I have the following switches set:

1. --allow-file-access-from-files
2. --allow-file-access
3. --disable-web-security

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 2):

Try `--disable-web-security` parameter

Comment: @RobG I've tried with `--disable-web-security` only and it works fine on Chrome 14 & Chromium 15 on Ubuntu 11.04. My sample attached below:

    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html
    <body>
    <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', './xml.xml');
    xhr.send(null, true);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>`